# Remove all previous versions of python

Tags: python, uninstallation

I have some experience with `C++` and `Fortran`, and I want to start using `python` for my post-processing as I am starting to realise how inefficient `MATLAB` is for what I need to do (mostly involves plots with millions of points).

I already had a few versions of `python` installed, from every time I wanted to start using. It has now become a mess. In `/usr/local/bin/`, here is what the command `ls python*` returns:

```
python            python2.7         python3           python3.5         python3.5m        pythonw-32
python-32         python2.7-32      python3-32        python3.5-32      python3.5m-config pythonw2.7 
python-config     python2.7-config  python3-config    python3.5-config  pythonw           pythonw2.7-32
```

I now want a clean slate. I want a safe way to remove all the previous versions of `python`, including all of their packages, so I can just install the latest version and import all the libraries I want like `numpy` and `matplotlib` smoothly (I had some issues with that).

**EDIT:**

I am running on OSX Yosemite 10.10.

Comment: From what I can see you have two versions of Python: 2.7 and 3.5. 2.7 is used by system and it's not recommended to remove it. 3.5 is the latest version of Python. Anyway to get help you should at least mention what OS are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not uninstall your system's Python interpreter (Python 2.7 most probably). You might consider uninstalling the other version (Python 3.5 most probably), but I do not think you really need to do that (it may not be a bad idea to keep a system-wide Python 3 interpreter... who knows!).

If you want a clean state I would recommend you to use virtual environments for now on. You have two options:

- Use [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to setup your virtual environments and packages. However, using `pip` means you will have to compile the packages that need compilation (`numpy`, `matplotlib` and many other scientific Python packages that you may use for your "post-processing").
- Use Conda (or [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html)). This way you will be able to handle virtual
  environments but without having to compile Python packages yourself.
  Conda also allows you to handle different Python interpreters without
  the need of having them installed in your system (it will download
  them for you).

Also, you say you are feeling MATLAB is inefficient for plotting millions of points. I do not know your actual needs/constraints, but I find Matplotlib to be very inefficient for plotting large data and/or real-time data.

Just as a suggestion, consider using [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/). If you still feel that is not fast enough, consider using VisPy (probably less functional/convenient at the moment, but more [efficient](http://vispy.org/)).