# traceback error - python

Tags: string, input

my code was working find on Win machine , python 3.6 then i try the code on mac - terminal and its showing me error. Also have install latest version of python 
my code:

```
print ("==================================")
print ("    Print all String Character    ")
print ("==================================")

word_secund = input("Please add your word: ")
word_one = str(word_secund)

def list(text):
    word = 0
    for word in text:
        print(word)
print (list(word_one))
```

error message:

```
Please add your word: Slavo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strings.py", line 5, in <module>
    word_secund = input("Please add your word: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Slavo' is not defined
```

Comment: try `raw_input` instead of `input` i suspect that although you have installed the latest version of python on your Mac you have two version of python installed on your machine and it is taken the python 2+ as default.

Comment: I think you are right and I have conflict

Answer (score 1):

This error happens with python2. Note that on Mac and Linux, the default python is python2. Try to run your program with the command

```
python3 yourfile.py
```

To avoid the error.

Comment: Thanks men I will

Comment: You are welcome. Please, don't forget to approve one of the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

check your python version "python --version" in command line. You might have more than 1 version installed and you might be using 2.x

Or try using raw_input instead of input. If that works, you're using 2.x

**EDIT:**

> How can I remove the older version of Python because 100 % this is the problem

You might not want to remove the Python 2.7 which is by default used by your system. Check this answer: [Remove all previous versions of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033747/remove-all-previous-versions-of-python)

How are you running your python program? If you are using a command line with the command "python name.py", you could just replace "python" with "python3" to run it with the python 3 interpreter. If you are using an IDE, they have an option to select the python interpreter, and you can select the 3.x there.

Comment: How can I remove the older version of Python because 100 % this is the problem.