# How to remove python 2.7 from Mac OS X 10.14.5?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, uninstallation

I realise that there is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4) for the question but its for Mac OS X 10.6.4 and the python he installed was from "python.org". My python 2.7 has come built-in in my Mac so how do I remove it? Is there any way of removing it? I have installed a python3.7 from the website and it is working perfectly but 2.7 is also working. I want to remove 2.7 and make it such that when i type "python" in terminal it runs python3.7 and not 2.7.

Comment: You could alias the `python` command to be `python3`. Much easier and you'll have the option to use py2.7 if you'll ever need it (usually older py projects) To alias check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967843/how-do-i-create-a-bash-alias)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't have to remove python 2.7. You can simply add the command as an alias (you can also add this in your `~/.bash_profile` file):

```
alias python='python3.7'
```

**Do not remove python 2.7** (default python package), it may damage your operating system.

If you want you can simply use this command (removes the python installed with homebrew):

```
brew uninstall python
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4) question if you really thinking of removing python 2.7. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033747/remove-all-previous-versions-of-python) is another question which will give you more information.

Comment: Note: If you have multiple versions of Python on your machine and you decide to `brew uninstall` it, you'll have to specify which version you want brew to remove.

Comment: The best advice

Answer (score 2):

the 2.7 version of python is a bundle that comes along with the MAC Unix operating system. which means maybe you not using it but there are some pre-loaded programs and dependencies which uses python hence you cannot remove it completely. If you want to use python 3 directly from the terminal's command line just use "python3" in place of "python". this will launch python 3.* what ever you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

A Mac has more Pythons than a Malaysian jungle.

A new Mac M1 has version 2.7 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

If you use Homebrew to install Vim, it uses /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9, and it warns you if you delete it, Vim won't work.

Meantime, I want to do the introductory tensorflow machine learning course, and it insists on Python 3.8

So in my .bash_profile

alias python='/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.8_1/bin/python3'

alias python3='python'

alias python3.8='python3'

and I deleted all references to Python2.7.

But when I  open a new terminal, and run a Python program which does

print(sys.path)

it includes /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7

and tensorflow won't work. The Mac is inserting its own Python into what I want.